# overwrite ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

as all of us, I have some application. In database I store sensitive data and I want to overwrite ActiveRecord (or somewhere else?) to always add `AND user_id = current_user` statement to all SQL queries sent to database (I will add user_id column to all tables). I basically want to ensure, that all operations done by user, are performed ONLY on his data.

Regards, 
Mateusz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like what you're after is a strategy for implementing multitenancy in your application.

You might want to checkout the [multitenant gem](https://github.com/wireframe/multitenant) which can help you to isolate your queries to data belonging to the current tenant.

Alternatively, you can enforce this at the database level using PostgreSQL schemas. Gay Naor has an [excellent talk](http://www.bestechvideos.com/2009/03/26/acts_as_conference-2009-writing-multi-tenant-applications-in-rails) on implementing this strategy among others.

If you search on "multi-tenant rails apps" you'll find several other discussions on this problem.

Comment: this presentation is great! I think I'll use Schema separation. Thanks for links!

Comment: No worries, glad they were helpful. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to enforce it on application level, the only way to enforce it is to forbid to team to use Class.find/where/etc methods and allow to call them only on collections. So instead of Task.find you should always use current_user.tasks.find etc.

Comment: Are you sure, that I cannot overwrite .find method?

Answer (score 0):

You can add AbstractModel with default scope and then inherit all other models from it:

```
class AbstractModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  default_scope where(:user_id => Thread.current[:current_user])
end

class SomeModel < AbstractModel
  ...
end
```

I've used `Thread.current[:current_user]` because of current_user is inaccessible inside of models. You should assign current_user to Thread.current in some before_filter method in ApplicationController etc.

Comment: Yes, That would also do! As I just found in other comment, I'll use Schema separation. Thanks anyway.